# The default behavior of "di("

Tags: normal-mode, cursor-motions, object-motions

As is well known, `di(`  deletes the contents inside a `()` block. When the cursor is not within a group of `()`, the cursor jumps to the near `()` group and delete the contents in it.

Is there any way to disable this jumping?

Namely, if the cursor is not within a group, then just do nothing.

Comment: This is rather funny because `i(` didn't work like that for *a long time* and people have been asking for and writing plugins to fix the discrepancy between `i"` and `i(` for decades. Now that the default behavior has been changed to match user expectations, people are starting to ask for the original behavior. I guess one could take one of the old workarounds and reverse it?

Comment: @romainl but hey, Vim is my editor, not everyone's editor :)

Comment: @goaqiang, how can we help you further? Do you have something open in your question? If not maybe could you accept an answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
nnoremap <expr> di( (searchpairpos('(', '', ')', 'n') == [0, 0] ? '' : 'di(')
```

The `searchpairpos('(', '', ')', 'n')` call searches for a matching pair without moving the cursor (the `n` flag). If it doesn't find a matching pair it returns `[0, 0]`

The mapping map the `di(` to:

- the empty string if no matching is pair is found,
- `di(` otherwise

As suggested by @filbranden another solution would be to `onoremap` to make it working for all the verbs (`d`, `y` and `c`) you could do:

```
onoremap <expr> i( (searchpairpos('(', '', ')', 'n') == [0, 0] ? '\<Esc>' : 'i(')
```

In order to make it work for `v` you could do:

```
xnoremap <expr> i( (searchpairpos('(', '', ')', 'n') == [0, 0] ? '\<Esc>' : 'i(')
```

Remark: Both mappings work fine with count (e.g. `2di(`)

Comment: I think this solution could be improved by using an `onoremap <expr> i(` to have the `i(` text object work in all contexts, not only after `d`, and a corresponding `xnoremap i(` to have it also work in Visual mode. There's also other possibly relevant corner cases, such as passing a count, also considering similar text objects such as `a(` and possible synonyms such as `i)` and `a)` (though maybe those could be left with the original behavior?) This is a great start, but as usual, it's a lot of work to make things really robust in Vimscript :-)

Comment: @filbranden, thanks for the feedback. I'll try my best :-)